# How can I group strings based on their length?

Tags: java

```
public class sortingtext {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String  readline="i have a sentence with words";
            String[] words=readline.split(" ");

            Arrays.sort(words, (a, b)->Integer.compare(b.length(), a.length()));

            for (int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
            {
                int len = words[i].length();

                int t=0;

                System.out.println(len +"-"+words[i]);
            }

        }
```

input:

> i have a sentence with words

My code split a string and then it should print each word and their length.

The output I get looks like:

> 8- sentence
>
> 5- words
>
> 4- have
>
> 4-with
>
> 1-I
>
> 1-a

I want to group the words of same length to get that:

> 8- sentence
>
> 5- words
>
> 4- have ,with
>
> 1- I ,a

But I don't get how to group them.

Comment: can you explan your question a little more?

Comment: i have one sentence . i have to split the sentence and group the word by its character length.
input: i have a sentence with words 
 Expected output:

8- sentence 
5- words 
4- have with 
1-I a

Comment: "character length"? Do you mean word length?

Comment: So far you only sort the words based on their length but you make no effort in "grouping" them. Why? Where is your attempt?

Comment: After spliting your input you can use a `Map<Integer,List<String>>` to group your substrings by their length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a beginner or not familiar with stream API:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String  readline= "i have a sentence with words";
    String[] words = readline.split(" ");
    Arrays.sort(words, (a, b)->Integer.compare(b.length(), a.length()));
    // declare a variable to hold the current string length
    int currLength = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i<words.length; i++){
        if(currLength == words[i].length()){
            // if currLength is equal to current word length just append a comma and this word
            System.out.print(", "+words[i]);
        }
        else{
            // if not update currLength, jump to a new line and print new length with the current word
            currLength = words[i].length();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print(currLength+ " - "+words[i]);                
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The println("...") method prints the string "..." and moves the cursor to a new line. The print("...") method instead prints just the string "...", but does not move the cursor to a new line. Hence, subsequent printing instructions will print on the same line. The println() method can also be used without parameters, to position the cursor on the next line.

Comment: `(a, b)->Integer.compare(b.length(), a.length())` could also be written as  `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)`

Answer (score 3):

Easy with the stream API:

```
final Map<Integer, List<String>> lengthToWords = new TreeMap<>(
    Arrays.stream(words)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length))
);
```

The stream groups the words by length into a map (implementation detail, but it will be a HashMap), the `TreeMap` then sorts this map based on the key (the word length).

Alternatively, you can write it like this which is more efficient but in my opinion less readable.

```
final Map<Integer, List<String>> lengthToWords = Arrays.stream(words)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: please add necessary imports